# how to make an installed package as a service in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, openconnect

I've installed ocserv package using these commands on Ubuntu22:

```
mkdir /usr/local/src/ocserv
cd /usr/local/src/ocserv
wget ftp://ftp.infradead.org/pub/ocserv/ocserv-0.10.9.tar.xz
unxz ocserv-0.10.9.tar.xz
tar xvf ocserv-0.10.9.tar
cd ocserv-0.10.9
./configure --sysconfdir=/etc/ && make && make install
```

The ocserv package is installed and it run and works with this command:

```
ocserv -c /etc/ocserv/ocserv.conf
```

I need it to run as a service. can you please help me doing this?

- I couldn't use the linux repository to install this package because of some considerations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Sergiu, with some modification to his instructions, I finally managed to run ocserv as a system service in ubuntu.

First I wanted to edit Sergiu's post but then I thought it may not be right.
So I put the edited instruction here.

First create a systemd unit for this service:

```
systemctl edit --force --full ocserv.service
```

With these contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=OCServ service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=1
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/ocserv --foreground --pid-file /var/run/ocserv.pid --config /etc/ocserv/ocserv.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Save it and enable the new service:

```
systemctl enable --now ocserv.service
```

You can view its status with this command:

```
systemctl status ocserv.service
```

If the service was inactive or had any error:

```
systemctl restart ocserv.service
```

And recheck the service status:

```
systemctl status ocserv.service
```

Comment: I don't think that copying my answer almost verbatim and then accepting your copy is the best way to go.

Comment: Dear Sergiu. I mentioned you name. Your answer didn't work and needed some mods. If I have had chosen It as best answer, others with same issue may confuse.

Comment: If you edit you answer I would select it as best answer.

Answer (score 0):

First create a systemd unit for this service:

```bash
systemctl edit --force --full ocserv.service
```

With these contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=OCServ service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=1
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/ocserv -c /etc/ocserv/ocserv.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Save it and enable the new service:

```bash
systemctl enable --now ocserv.service
```

You can view its status with this command:

```bash
systemctl status ocserv.service
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for the explanation. I did all the steps but service remains inactive. I'll share some logs in a new post

Answer (score 0):

`systemctl status ocserv`
it should automatically create service for you. if you are talking about openconnect **server**.

however if you are talking about vpn client and you want the client to automatically connect to vpn server at **startup** do the steps below

`nano /etc/systemd/system/openconnect.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Connect to VPN
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=password=correcthorsebatterystaple
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'echo password | sudo openconnect -u username --passwd-on-stdin vpn.dixmata.com'
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable openconnect.service --now
```

Comment: no I'm talking about openconnect server (ocserv).

Comment: `systemctl status ocserv` what is the result of this command ?